# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.MultiTenantConnectionProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

Good morning, I 'm trying to implement a multi-tenancy Java project ( Primefaces , EJBs , Hibernate 5 / JPA - Postgres ).

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
       <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence>
<persistence-unit name="myDS" transaction-type="JTA">

    <jta-data-source>java:/myDS</jta-data-source>

    <class>com.arkin.erpmodel.general.entities.AccountingDocumentType</class>
    <class>com.arkin.erpmodel.general.entities.AccountingOperation</class>
    <class>com.arkin.erpmodel.general.entities.AccountingYear</class>
    <class>com.arkin.erpmodel.general.entities.AccountingYearPeriod</class>    

    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA"/>
            <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.arkin.erpmodel.multitenancyprovider.SchemaResolver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.arkin.erpmodel.multitenancyprovider.MultiTenantProvider"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="org.hibernate.type" value="debug" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20"/>
            <!-- Turn on entity and query cache statistics in the admin console -->
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <!-- store entries in the cache in a more human friendly format - helps when interpreting logs -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="false" />
            <!-- MultiTenancy -->           
    </properties>    
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[Maven Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAbxL.jpg)

I could help know why not recognize the MultiTenantConnectionProvider class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the readme in `hibernate-entitymanager` it says

> Hibernate's JPA support has been merged into the hibernate-core
>   module, making this hibernate-entitymanager module obsolete.  This
>   module will be removed in Hibernate ORM 6.0.  It is only kept here for
>   various consumers that expect a static set of artifact names across a
>   number of Hibernate releases. See
>   https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10823

Now, you need to use hibernate-core

The `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` is located in

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi package of `hibernate-core`
```

You can include this maven dependancy:-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```